# Camunda database. Save id's instead of object

Tags: database, variables, transactions, bpmn, camunda

Good whatever time of day applies,

I have a problem with camunda database. When session between user tasks need to be finished, camunda persists all variables from VariableStore to database (ACT_RU_VARIABLE). But I want to save just Id 's of objects (in case of session fail I m gonna restore object from my own database by this id). This must reduse database load. (Camunda database load).  Can I use setVariable just for VariableStore without further persisting?

Answer (score 1):

I have found some solution. Its using transient variables. Such variables is not persisted to database but they are lost 
as well when the wait state come.